# jQuery: Add validation rules from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add validation rules to a set of controls that are specified in an array using the following code:

```
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var fieldname = data[i].field_id;
    alert(fieldname);

    $("#EditView").validate({
        rules:{
            fieldname:{
                maxlength:60
            },
            messages: {
                fieldname: ""
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The above code it does not add any rules to the control, but if i use the code below which set manually to only one control it works.

```
   $("#EditView").validate({
            rules:{
                street_1_c:{
                    maxlength:60
                },
                messages: {
                    street_1_c: ""
                }
            }
        });
```

Any help why this happens ?

Comment: Can't find an exact duplicate right now, but the point is, you cannot use variables on the left side of `:` - only literal values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to do this?

```
var vObj = {};
vObj.rules = {};
vObj.rules.messages = {};

for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  var fieldname = data[i].field_id;
  vObj.rules[fieldname] = { maxlength: 60 };
  vObj.rules.messages[fieldname] = '';
}

$("#EditView").validate(vObj);
```